# Docker image size is too large (500 MB) for normal spring boot app with 78MB

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In the docker history command result one of the layer image is with 321MB.

Can someone help me to understand why that layer is added and what's the purpose? How can I reduce the size?

Output of docker images

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                                                           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
kpay/customers-engagement-services                                   latest              6c126293ca3d        30 minutes ago      515MB
adoptopenjdk/openjdk11                                               latest              140cc9900b0e        40 hours ago        437MB
```

output of docker history

```
$ docker history 6c126293ca3d
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
6c126293ca3d        19 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENTRYPOINT ["java" "-ja...   0B                  
617dde94b409        19 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /usr/apps             0B                  
006090d4e50d        19 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:c0dfd5789147f2...   78MB                
a6ee69cf5313        20 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV APP_HOME=/usr/apps       0B                  
972fea15c944        20 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV APP_FILE=customers-...   0B                  
140cc9900b0e        40 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["jshell"]               0B                  
<missing>           40 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV JAVA_HOME=/opt/java...   0B                  
<missing>           40 hours ago        /bin/sh -c set -eux;     ARCH="$(dpkg --pr...   321MB               
<missing>           40 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV JAVA_VERSION=jdk-11...   0B                  
<missing>           40 hours ago        /bin/sh -c apt-get update     && apt-get i...   43.2MB              
<missing>           40 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LA...   0B                  
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["bash"]                 0B                  
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:920cf788d1ba88f...   72.7MB
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:latest
ENV APP_FILE customers-service.jar
ENV APP_HOME /usr/apps
COPY $APP_FILE $APP_HOME/
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "customers-service.jar"]
```

Comment: What do you think is too large? That layer is from the openjdk base image. Do you think 437MB is too large for a jdk image?

Comment: A docker image includes a base linux distro (mins the kernel) plus, in your case, jdk11, and then your app on top. Your problem is that you think your app is only 78mb, when that's just your jar file, not your app -- your app is huge.

Comment: understood. I have switched to jre based image instead of jdk to reduce the size. thanks

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your base image (`adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:latest`) is fairly large. You might try switching to a base image that uses [alpine linux](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine) as the base image, because they tend to be much smaller.

It looks like there is an available image with the tag `adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:x86_64-alpine-jdk-11.0.11_9-slim` which is only 125MB, down from 437MB for your current base image.

This means changing your Dockerfile from something that starts with:

`FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11`

to

`FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:x86_64-alpine-jdk-11.0.11_9-slim`

If that doesn't work for you, you can explore other image tags from adoptopenjdk [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/adoptopenjdk/openjdk11/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated) to find one that suits your requirements.

Comment: thanks @wedm, I have found another article explaining about different images and sizes.,https://medium.com/@ievgen.degtiarenko/reduce-size-of-docker-image-with-spring-boot-application-2b3632263350. Using adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre image, I see significant reduction in overall image size.